# delete all characters after specific character, not character itself, in whole column, python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, character

I have a data frame that I made into a dict for reproducibility purposes. I want to delete all characters after the last "1" in the "index" column, not deleting "1" itself. Does someone know how to quickly do this? I tried the following but it also deleted the "1":

```
df1['index'] = [x.split('1')[-1] for x in df1['index']]
```

```
{0: {'1': 0.001549586776859504,
  '10': 0.001549586776859504,
  '11': 0.00017217630853994488,
  '12': 4.304407713498622e-05,
  '13': 0.00012913223140495865},
 1: {'1': 0.000387396694214876,
  '10': 0.000387396694214876,
  '11': nan,
  '12': nan,
  '13': nan},
 2: {'1': 0.001162190082644628,
  '10': 0.001162190082644628,
  '11': 9.838646202282564e-05,
  '12': 2.459661550570641e-05,
  '13': 7.378984651711923e-05},
 3: {'1': 0.015883264462809916,
  '10': 0.015883264462809916,
  '11': 0.0006149153876426602,
  '12': 0.00015372884691066505,
  '13': 0.0004611865407319952},
 4: {'1': 0.00387396694214876,
  '10': 0.00387396694214876,
  '11': 0.00012298307752853205,
  '12': 3.0745769382133014e-05,
  '13': 9.223730814639904e-05},
 5: {'1': 0.001549586776859504,
  '10': 0.001549586776859504,
  '11': nan,
  '12': nan,
  '13': nan},
 6: {'1': 0.005423553719008264,
  '10': 0.005423553719008264,
  '11': 0.0002951593860684769,
  '12': 7.378984651711923e-05,
  '13': 0.00022136953955135768},
 7: {'1': 0.001549586776859504,
  '10': 0.001549586776859504,
  '11': 0.00017217630853994488,
  '12': 4.304407713498622e-05,
  '13': 0.00012913223140495865},
 8: {'1': 0.001162190082644628,
  '10': 0.001162190082644628,
  '11': nan,
  '12': nan,
  '13': nan},
 9: {'1': 0.001549586776859504,
  '10': 0.001549586776859504,
  '11': 7.378984651711923e-05,
  '12': 1.8447461629279807e-05,
  '13': 5.534238488783942e-05},
 'index': {'1': '00', '10': '000', '11': '0', '12': '20', '13': '30'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution convert int to string then search for first number different number from zero then take the partition you need (from begining to the position of the number different from zero) and convert it back to float. ***happy coding***

```
df1['index']=[float(x[:x.find(x.split(".")[-1].replace("0","")[0])+1]) for x in list(map(str,df1['index']))]
```

Comment: Thank you. This removes the p in front of first 1 and I want to remove everything after the last 1 in the string

Comment: try this new solution

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or
why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.